# Prove through induction that $f(x) = x^2e^{-x} \Rightarrow (-1)^n(x^2-2nx+n(n-1))e^{-x}=f^{(n)}(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, induction

The function is,  $f\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^2e^{-x}$ and I need to prove, through mathematical induction that the following function is true for all $n∈\mathbb N$ and $x∈\mathbb R$,
$$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n(x^2-2nx+n(n-1))e^{-x}$$
So I started with $n=0$ and got $$f^{(0)}(x)=(-1)^0(x^2-2(0)x+0(0-1))e^{-x} =(1)(x^2)(e^{-x})=f(x)$$
So it works for $n=0$ and I make the assumption that it will work for all $n∈\mathbb N$. The I moved on to show that because it works for $n=0$ and thus all $n∈\mathbb N$, it must also work for all $n=n+1$.
So I let $n=n+1$ and get:

$$f^{(n+1)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}(x^2-2(n+1)x+(n+1)((n+1)-1))e^{-x}$$

The I specifically state that $a(x) =(-1)^{n}(x^2-2(n)x+(n)(n-1))$ and $b(x)=e^{-x}$

Then I apply the product rule to find the derivative of $f^n(x)$

$f^{{(n)}'}(x)=a(x)'b(x) +b(x)'a(x) =(-1)^n(2x-2n)$

Now here is the funny part, I did this problem a while back and didn't write how I found the derivative of $f^{(n)}$ and I don't know how to continue from here. So any help in explaining and/or the next step and/or the derivative of $f^{(n)}$ would be of great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just made a mistake when calculating $f^{(n)'}(x)$.

It should be:

\begin{align}
f^{(n+1)}(x) &= f^{(n)'}(x)\\
&= \Big[(-1)^n(x^2 - 2nx + n(n-1))e^{-x}\Big]'\\
&= (-1)^n\Big[(-x^2 + 2nx + n(n-1))e^{-x} + (2x - 2n)e^{-x}\Big]\\
&= -(-1)^{n}(-x^2 + 2(n+1)x - n(n+1))e^{-x}\\
&= (-1)^{n+1}(x^2 - 2(n+1)x + n(n+1))e^{-x}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$a(x)'b(x)=(-1)^n(2x-2)e^{-x},\ b(x)'a(x)=(-1)^{n+1}(x^2-2nx+n(n-1))e^{-x}$.
Combine these 2 expressions to get what you need.

The last part of your last expression $=(-1)^n(2x-2n)$ is wrong.